# How to find the users by their email address

Tags: support, search, users, email

Is there a way to find out the users by their *email address* on a Stack Exchange site?

I tried putting the email in the search box, but I got no results.

Any other methods?

Comment: If you understand how gravatar works and hash their email, then you might be able to do what you want if the user has been on the site for a long time and hasn't recently changed their email.  The newer hashes are salted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. A user's email address and/or OpenID information are not public information and users cannot search for them. This is not a social network, and there's not really any reason why someone would need to locate another user by email address anyways. If you do *really* know someone and you have some legitimate reason to know their account on a site, go ask them in person.